# XAML - is LayoutRoot mandatory?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

When you create a XAML page in Silverlight or WPF, the system creates a top level container called "LayoutRoot". Is there anything special about this name, or can the top level container be called anything (or even nothing)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can absolutely call it whatever you like. There is nothing special about the LayoutRoot name.

I have to ask though, and I don't mean to seem facetious, did you try removing the name and seeing what happens?

Comment: Hehe, no probs :) Confirmation is always a good thing. And I'm sure there will be other surfing the net that are asking the same question.

Comment: @AlastairPitts : you bet there will